# Ignoring certain rows while adding into SQL Database from DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following data to insert to SQL from DataTable in C#. How do I check if tracking_id is already in DB and NOT insert it?

```
|    id    |    invoice_no    |    tracking_id    |    account_id    |
|    1     |     1234556      | 1ZRF3844679912330 |    0000RF3123    |
|    2     |     1234556      | 1ZRF3844679912331 |    0000RF3123    |
|    3     |     1234558      | 1ZRF3844679912322 |    0000RF3123    |
|    4     |     1234558      | 1ZRF3844679912333 |    0000RF3123    |
|    5     |     1234556      | 1ZRF3844679912335 |    0000RF3123    |
|    6     |     1234556      | 1ZRF3844679912337 |    0000RF3123    |
|    7     |     1234557      | 1ZRF3844679912338 |    0000RF3123    |
|    8     |     1234557      | 1ZRF3844679912339 |    0000RF3123    |
|    9     |     1234550      | 1ZRF3844679912310 |    0000RF3123    |
|    10    |     1234550      | 1ZRF3844679912311 |    0000RF3123    |
|    11    |     1234551      | 1ZRF3844679912349 |    0000RF3123    |
```

Let's say record with ID 10 has the tracking no. already in DB, how to ignore this record while inserting others?

Edit : code inserting data to sql:

```
 public static bool BulkSaveData(Dictionary<string, DataTable> dtEntries, string duplicatesDateFieldName)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Invoice"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    //Bulk insert into the temporal tables
                    foreach (var dtEntry in dtEntries)
                    {
                        var dt = dtEntry.Value;
                        if (dt == null || dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                            continue;

                        using (var s = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
                        {
                            s.DestinationTableName = dt.TableName;

                            s.ColumnMappings.Clear();
                            foreach (var column in dt.Columns)
                                s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());

                            s.WriteToServer(dt);
                        }
                    }
                }

                scope.Complete();
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SqlLogger.Logger.LogException(ex);
        }

        return false;
```

Comment: Please post your code here as well with problem statement.

Comment: First try to filter the datatable.

Comment: Do an update query,  The return value is the number of rows changed.  If the primary key is not in the database then the number of rows changed will be zero.  So you then perform an Insert.

Comment: You can use MERGE command to insert the new data and update the old data

Comment: Could you first get the existing rows and then in your select statement exclude those rows ie "not in(x,y,z)" ?

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to create a unique index on tracking_id and trap error in your Code loop.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX YOURINDEXNAME ON YOURTABLENAME(tracking_id);
```